# message to screen won't stop after set number of time

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a game and right now I want to display a welcome screen for 5 seconds. I have typed into google this problem and there are a lot of results but nothing is working. I see this problem has been covered in stack overflow before also but that is not working for me. I have tried `time.sleep`, `pygame.time.set`, `pygame.time.tick`, and many more. This is the code I have right now but I was making changes to it before to. Here is the code and thanks in advance.

```
#I imported all these mods just in case I need them, that way I don't have to worry about it
import math
import random
import time
import pygame
import cx_Freeze
import os
import superwires
import sys
import pip
import glob
from pygame import *
pygame.init()
move=0
FPS=60
blue=(0,0,255)
white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
green=(0,155,0)
display_width=800
display_height=600
gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Stacker')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
smallfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",25)
mediumfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",50)
largefont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",80)
gamedisplay.fill(green)
pygame.display.update()
def welcome_screen():
    welcome_message = largefont.render(str("Welcome to Stacker!!!"), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(welcome_message,(87,25))
    pygame.display.update()
play=True
while play==True:
    welcome_screen()
    pygame.time.delay(5)
    play=False
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: When posting code try to make [minimal complete working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in particular you should remove any imports that you don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to pygame.time.delay is a number of milliseconds. To pause for 5 seconds `pygame.time.delay(5000)`

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay

I note that you import pygame twice first as `import pygame` and then again as `from pygame import *` That's unnecessary. Only import the modules you need and only import each one once.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

black=(0,0,0)
green=(0,155,0)
display_width=800
display_height=600
largefont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",80)

gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
gamedisplay.fill(green)

def welcome_screen():
    welcome_message = largefont.render(str("Welcome to Stacker!!!"), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(welcome_message,(87,25))
    pygame.display.update()

welcome_screen()
pygame.time.delay(5000)
```

Comment: That is still far from a minimal example. Start from scratch. Only include the modules that you are actually using in the example. Don't make assignments or defintions that you aren't using in the example. "that did not work" isn't a description of a problem. What do you expect it to do? When I ran your code (with delay(5000)) the message "Welcome to Stacker" was displayed for 5 seconds, the the program exited. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Ok, I took your advice and deleted some of the modules I am pretty sure I won't use. The ones left I am confident I will use. I tried doing the pygame.time.delay(5000) but that did not work. Here is the script from my code right now. Sorry about the code not being centered on this. while play==True:
    welcome_screen()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(5000)
    play=False

Comment: I was trying to comment as it was giving me problems xd. I want the message to disappear after 5 seconds leaving the green screen, not exiting the program.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. I stopped using the while loop and called the message function and then did time delay like you said. Then I just filled the screen with a green background again. Then updated it. Works fine now. Thanks for the help.